# Check if Voltage is in a certain range

Tags: power-supply, voltage, range-detector

I did not really found anything on google to accomplish my idea, so try here to find out an answer:

My task is defined as follows: I need to check if the input voltage is in a specific range. Lets say, for example: 5V +/- 10% so Vmin=4.5V and Vmax=5.5V. If the input voltage is in the acceptable range then light up a LED and start a microcontroller else do nothing at all.

The problem: the voltage I want to check is the only voltage available, so I can't compare it to another for example.

I already came up with a solution but I don't think its perfect: use a simple zener diode in reverse and wait until it becomes conductive and then switch a transistor or so.

Is there a better and more professional way to do it?

**EDIT**:
I just found a Voltage Detector IC ([click](http://datasheet.sii-ic.com/en/voltage_detector/S1009_E.pdf)) with a really low supply voltage, would that be an  acceptable solution?

Comment: *I just found a Voltage Detector IC...* Part number?

Comment: Voltage detector- if you mean the one that keeps microcontroller in reset, than it's fine, but it usually only  checks the undervoltage condition. Also it is actually integrated comparator with voltage reference and voltage divider. And also, if this is a homework, i bet your teacher expects to see zener reference and comparator.

Comment: How low can the voltage go, and still need to get a correct output?

Comment: If correct behavior at low voltage (say below 2.5 V) is not required, then look for other q/a on the site about *window comparators*.

Comment: @ThePhoton Should not be less than 5V actually.

Comment: Are you sure you need to detect voltage > 5.5? Assuming your supply is connected to the microcontroller, there's not much you can do about it. Otherwise, your linked IC is fine for what you need. Search for "voltage supervisor" circuits.

Comment: In real situations you almost always want a hardware delay after the voltage comes within range before releasing the micro from reset. There are lots of supervisory ICs that integrated low-voltage detect and a hardware timer. If you want to detect overvoltage for some reason, add another comparator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zener is actually a good idea. Later you can replace it with voltage reference IC for better accuracy, but zener is just fine for your application.

You need two low voltage comparators, each will have a reference voltage set by a zener (with resistor in series! and a capacitor for cleaner signal...) and each will have a voltage divider (two resistors) with your input voltage on top. And- some basic logic on comparators outputs.

Comment: Are low voltage comparators comparators with a very low voltage supply? If so, that would be great!

Comment: Ok, define very low.  LT6703 takes 1.4V, and actually incudes a voltage reference inside. You must remember, that any number is only valid in certain limits, which are usually defined by application. I mean, if you really really need to, you can design your own comparator that will work with VCC as low as 0.8V. Maybe you can find one like that. But for described application you just don't need it, because your microcontroller will not run with voltage lower than, say, 3V. So your problem is only relevant to voltages higher than 1.5V or 2V

Comment: You are right, I just thought of a solution without a microcontroller involved but that was not the question, so the comparator + zener diode solution seems like a good solution to me now

Comment: Oh, i thought you need to keep the MCU in reset. This is a very common application. google voltage supervisor.

Comment: Actually, that is exactly what I need, but why should this not be accomplishable with a low voltage comparator?

Comment: It is acomplishable, no problem. Still, in real life you will look for cheap an reliable solution, which almost always means as few parta as possible. So there is plenty of such integrated solution that have zeners and resistors inside, cost cents, and this way reduce assembly costs and improve reliability.